# React - Testing external function in a functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-hooks

I have a functional component using react hooks. I have a function that updates the state of that component (**evaluateFunction**).

This update state function calls an external function for retrieving the data, something like this:

```js
import { calculatePerformanceTime } from "../../helpers/calculate-performance-time";

const getChallenge = challengeNumber =>
    calculatePerformanceTime(
        require(`../../../challenges/${challengeNumber}.js`)[
            `dcpChallenge${challengeNumber}`
        ],
        challengeNumber
    );

export const TestComponent = _ => {
    const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({});
    const [result, setResult] = useState({});
    const evaluateFunction = value => setResult(getChallenge(value)(inputs));
    return (
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => evaluateFunction(1)} />
        </div>
    );
};
```

When I simulate a click to test if `calculatePerformanceTime` has been called, it throws me this error:

```
TypeError: getChallenge(...) is not a function
```

I tried exporting **getChallenge** but it didn't work.

How can I test if that function it's been called when clicking on the button?

This is what I've been testing so far:

```js
import React from "react";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import { configure, shallow } from "enzyme";
import { ChallengeSolution } from "./ChallengeSolution";
import { calculatePerformanceTime } from "../../helpers/calculate-performance-time";
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

const mockFunction = jest.fn();
const mockInputData = 1;

jest.mock(`!raw-loader!../../challenges/1.js`, () => "MOCK_RAW", {
    virtual: true
});

jest.mock(`!raw-loader!../../challenges/2.js`, () => "MOCK_RAW", {
    virtual: true
});

jest.mock("../../helpers/calculate-performance-time.js");

describe("ChallengeSolutionComponent", () => {
    let wrapper;
    const tabNumber = 2;
    beforeEach(() => {
        wrapper = shallow(<ChallengeSolution selectedTab={tabNumber} />);
    });

    describe("when component was mount", () => {
        it("should render form correctly", () => {
            const title = wrapper.find(".challenge-solution__title");
            const button = wrapper.find(".challenge-solution__button");
            button.simulate("click");
            expect(calculatePerformanceTime).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect(title.text()).toEqual(`Daily Coding Solution #${tabNumber}`);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you share the code for `calculatePerformanceTime` and your test?  (Your code is expecting `getChallenge` to return a *function* but I can't see enough of your code to tell what is causing that to break during your test)

Comment: I've added the test I've been working on. I think the issue is caused because the component is a functional component and as `getChallenge` is outside, it can't reach it somehow... I can share `calculatePerformanceTime` if you want (it's quite long) although `getChallenge` is per se a function so it doesn't matter the result of `calculatePerformanceTime`

Comment: You don't need to test that at all. The code is not correct. Hooks are supopsed to be run in the top level only. Instead, you create a new function that will call the hook later. It's not a supported behavior. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#rules-of-hooks. 
UPD: or I might be misguided by your mentioning of hooks. Is this `calculatePerformanceTime` function a hook or a regular function?

Comment: No, `calculatePerformanceTime` is not related at all with hooks, is just a function that returns a certain value. I do use hooks at a top level, the issue was related with mocking that specific function. I needed to import `calculate-performance-time` as a global module in order to mock it correctly :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
jest.mock("../../helpers/calculate-performance-time.js");
```

...sets `calculatePerformanceTime` to an empty mock function that returns `undefined`.

Since `getChallenge` returns the result of calling `calculatePerformanceTime`, it also returns `undefined`.

Then, when this line runs:

```
const evaluateFunction = value => setResult(getChallenge(value)(inputs));
```

...it attempts to use the result of `getChallenge(...)` as a function and call it with `inputs`, but that fails because it is trying to call `undefined` as a function.

---

You need to mock `calculatePerformanceTime` to return a *function*:

```
import React from "react";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import { configure, shallow } from "enzyme";
import { ChallengeSolution } from "./ChallengeSolution";
import * as calculatePerformanceTimeModule from "../../helpers/calculate-performance-time";  // import the module
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

const mockFunction = jest.fn();
const mockInputData = 1;

jest.mock(`!raw-loader!../../challenges/1.js`, () => "MOCK_RAW", {
  virtual: true
});

jest.mock(`!raw-loader!../../challenges/2.js`, () => "MOCK_RAW", {
  virtual: true
});

const spy = jest.spyOn(calculatePerformanceTimeModule, 'calculatePerformanceTime');
spy.mockReturnValue(() => { /* this returns a function...fill in the return value here */ });

describe("ChallengeSolutionComponent", () => {
  let wrapper;
  const tabNumber = 2;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<ChallengeSolution selectedTab={tabNumber} />);
  });

  describe("when component was mount", () => {
    it("should render form correctly", () => {
      const title = wrapper.find(".challenge-solution__title");
      const button = wrapper.find(".challenge-solution__button");
      button.simulate("click");
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();  // Success!
      expect(title.text()).toEqual(`Daily Coding Solution #${tabNumber}`);
    });
  });
});
```